# Intersection Theory and Blow up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, blowup

The following is from Fulton's *Intersection Theory*:

> Theorem 6.7 (Blow-up Formula). Let $V$ be a $k$-dimensional subvariety of $Y$, and let $\widetilde{V} \subset \widetilde{Y}$ be the proper transform of $V$ , i.e. the blow-up of $V$ along $V \cap X$ . Then $$f^{*}[V] = [\widetilde{V}] + j_{*} \bigl \{c(E) \cap g^{*}s(V \cap X, V) \bigr \}_{k}$$ in $A_{k}\widetilde{Y}$.

$$ \require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\widetilde{X} @>j>> \widetilde{Y}
\\ @VV g V @VVfV
\\ X @>i >> Y
\end{CD}
$$

Where $f : \widetilde{Y} \longrightarrow Y$ is the blow up of $Y$ along $X$ with exceptional divisor $E$.

Now, for $Y = \mathbb{P}^{n}$ and $X \subset Y$ a smooth subvariety the second answer to the question   {https://mathoverflow.net/q/72710} we have

1) $\widetilde{H}^{n} = 1$,

2) $\widetilde{H}^{n-i} \cdot E^{i} = 0$ for $i < c = \text{codim}(X)$,

3)  $\widetilde{H}^{n-i} \cdot E^{i} = (-1)^{i-1}s_{i-c}H_{X}^{n-i}$ for $i \geq c$,

where $\widetilde{H} = f^{*}H$ is the pull-back of hyperplane class $H$ on $Y$, and $H_{X} = H\cdot X$.

Do these equalities come from the above theorem? How?

Every help is welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not an expert on intersection theory, but I don't think claims 1 & 2 need the theorem: by rational equivalence, you ought to be able to move the $n-i$ hyperplane classes so that they intersect in a $i$-dimensional linear subspace of $\Bbb P^n$ that avoids $X$, and then these claims are straightforwards. Claim 3 also looks like it ought to be a consequence of the [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segre_class) of the Segre class, (that is, without using the theorem) but I'm not totally sure. Hope this helps!

Comment: @KReiser. Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: If, at any time, you want to turn your comment above into an answer, I will appreciate it. I like the way you write and I learn a lot from your answers on this forum.

Comment: Minor comment: You are using the tilde to refer to the strict transform in the first half of your question ($\tilde{V}$) but to refer to the pullback in the second half ($\tilde{H}$). This is a little confusing.

Comment: @JakeLevinson. Sorry for the notation that caused the confusion part in the question. In the question asked in the forum (MathOverflow)  the author of the question cites this theorem and I cannot see why identities come from this result, so I mentioned it again in the body of the question.

Comment: @JakeLevinson. The $ \widetilde{H} $ notation quoted by you in your comment above is the notation written in the answer to the question. Anyway, thanks for the comment.